# Rails 3 to Rails 4 upgrade undefined method to_input_field_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm in the process of upgrading a Rails 3 application to Rails 4 and I get the error message `undefined method to_input_field_tag for class ActionView::Helpers::InstanceTag NameError` when trying to start the Rails server.

Looking at API Dock http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/InstanceTag/to_input_field_tag it shows this method as deprecated or moved.

Has this been moved or what is an equivalent replacement for this in Rails 4?

Comment: Can you provide more information about what's actually making a call to `to_input_field_tag`?

Comment: We will need to find how it's used to provide you with a valuable answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method has been deprecated and it appears that

```
ActionView::Helpers::InstanceTag
```

has been refactored into:

```
ActionView::Helpers::ActiveModelInstanceTag
```

Comparing the source code between Rails 3 and 4 it appears that the way input fields are rendered has changed:

```
# ~/rails-3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb

def text_field(object_name, method, options = {})
  InstanceTag.new(object_name, method, self, options.delete(:object)).to_input_field_tag("text", options)
end
```

Changed to:

```
# ~/rails-4-2-stable/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb

def text_field(object_name, method, options = {})
  Tags::TextField.new(object_name, method, self, options).render
end
```

It appears that many gems were affected by this change in the process of upgrading to Rails 4. So if this error is coming from a gem, check to see if a Rails 4 version is available.

If this code is something you wrote, then you can attempt to use the new Tags class depending on what exactly you're trying to accomplish.